# 400 (Bad Request) when calling listGroups() method with Google API PHP client

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, bad-request

I want to retrieve all groups in my domain. I'm using google api php client and have the following error when i try it :

```
$client = new Google_Client();

...

$directory = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

$directory->groups->listGroups();
```

Error calling `GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups: (400) Bad Request`

Do you know how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been fixed. I had to specify a domain in the listGroups() function :

```
$directory->groups->listGroups(array('domain' => 'mydomain.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue fixed by specifying `userKey` instead of `domain`